# How many maximum recursion possible for CTE in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How many maximum recursion level possible for CTE in SQL server? If maximum recursion level is reached then what are the alternative way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, it's `100`.

You can change it on per-query basis by appending a hint:

```
OPTION (MAXRECURSION N)
```

to the end of the query.

```
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

means no explicit limit.

When the recursion limit is reached, an error is raised and the query breaks.

Comment: For SQL 2005, OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) The equal sign causes an error.